# How to format the Date field, by code, in a DetailsView grid?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, date

I'm simply databinding the data (containing date values) I got with a **DataReader** as in the following code:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Dim id As Integer = Request.QueryString("id")

    'Start connection
    Dim cs As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("Access 2010").ConnectionString
    Dim cn As New OleDbConnection(cs)
    cn.Open()

    'Retrieve Jobs Data
    Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand
    With cmd
        .Connection = cn
        .CommandText = "SELECT Nome, Descricao, Data, Autor FROM Jobs WHERE ID = @ID"
        .CommandType = CommandType.Text
        .Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", id)
    End With
    Dim dbReader As OleDbDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()

    If Not Page.IsPostBack Then
        'Populate Dropdown Jobs
        dtlJob.DataSource = dbReader
        dtlJob.DataBind()
    End If
    dbReader.Close()
End Sub
```

And I'm getting the values like **30/12/1899 00:00:51**. I checked my database and the record is correct: it appears 12/10/2011. How do I format the Date field since I just used `.DataSource` and `.DataBind`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find the details view on the aspx page and you need to add the `DataFromatString` tag to the bound field. IT will be something like this:

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="datetimefield" HeaderText="DateTime" DataFormatString="{0:d}" />
```

Comment: Whenever I add this, it doesn't join with the right Date Field and it stays as a independent field

Comment: Rodrigo I think you must have DetailsView set to auto generate the rows. In the tag for the details view you will have to put AutoGenerateRows="False"

Doing this though means you will have to add all your other field as bound field like above.